# Can we say that energy is always kinetic?

Tags: energy, potential-energy

[The wikipedia entry for energy states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy):

> Common forms of energy include the kinetic energy of a moving object,
>   the potential energy stored by an object's position in a force field
>   (gravitational, electric or magnetic), the elastic energy stored by
>   stretching solid objects, the chemical energy released when a fuel
>   burns, the radiant energy carried by light, and the thermal energy due
>   to an object's temperature.

I would classify elastic energy, and chemical energy as potential energy. At a scale small enough, they boil down to "the potential energy stored by an object's position in a force field".
Thermal energy is kinetic energy of particles.
Therefore it would seem that energy is always either kinetic or potential... If it wasn't for radiant energy that I don't know were to put. So can we say that energy is always kinetic (or a potential kinetic energy)?

Comment: No! The atomic interactions between a proton and an electron cannot be completely represented by kinetic energy alone. You need to take the electrostatic potential energy into account.

Comment: what statement are you saying "no" to ?

Comment: The statement is: can we say that energy is always kinetic?

Comment: ok please read the last sentence of my post "So can we say that energy is always kinetic (or a potential kinetic energy)?"

Comment: Isn't "potential kinetic energy" kind of an oxymoron? Either it is kinetic or potential. But your question title seems to say otherwise...

Comment: if you agree that energy is only either kinetic or potential then it follows that when the "potential energy" turns into "real energy" that real energy will be cinetic

Comment: What's the point of this? Certainly you *can* say that all energy is kinetic - you just did, it's a matter of how you define "kinetic", most people would use a different definition. But what physics question are you asking exactly?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I'm making sure that it's possible to define all energy as kinetic (kinetic being a mass moved by speed). I hint that radiant energy isnt so easy to put in that box because it has no rest mass

Answer (score 3):

Not just kinetic, calculating the total energy of a system requires the kinetic energy and the potential energy. A good example is the Hamiltonian in quantum mechanics, $\hat H$, used in the time-independent Schrodinger equation:

$$\hat H\Psi(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi(\mathbf{r})+V(\mathbf{r})\Psi(\mathbf{r})=E\Psi(\mathbf{r}). \tag{1}$$

In this equation $E$ is the total energy of the system and the two terms,

$$\hat T=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2 \qquad and \qquad \hat V =V(\mathbf{r}), \tag{2}$$

are the kinetic and potential energy operators. Adding them together and acting on the wave function returns the total energy, as shown in (1). You ask if energy is always kinetic energy or potential kinetic energy, the answer is yes, although the term is "potential energy" not "potential kinetic".